# Setting focus on toggled element

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an inline editing feature (using Angularjs) and I currently have the following in my Controller:

```
$scope.toggleEditor = function(){
  $scope.editorEnabled = !$scope.editorEnabled; //toggle editor view

  //can't get this part to work as desired
  $timeout(function(){
    angular.element("#email_editor").focus();
  },100);

}
```

The HTML is:

```
<div ng-hide="editorEnabled">
  <span class="editable" ng-click="toggleEditor()">{{user.local.email}}</span>
</div>
<div ng-show="editorEnabled">
  <input type="text" id="email_editor" ng-model="user.local.email" ng-blur="toggleEditor()">
</div>
```

The idea is that when a user clicks on the email address it shows a textbox with the email address in it. This parts works correctly but I would like the textbox to hide when the user clicks somewhere else. Because I'm using the `on-blur` directive the textbox must have focus for this to work.

**Question** How can I set the focus to the textbox once a user clicks on the email address. Please see my code for what I've tried.

Comment: Works here, you need to inject `$timeout`. http://plnkr.co/edit/tzLe15?p=preview Also i hope you have jquery loaded before angular. Another tip. It is not a good idea to access DOM in a controller

Comment: Oh bugger! I forgot that. thanks

Comment: How else can I set focus? - I've looked around and I found that code.

Comment: You could create a directive, a small one to do that...

Comment: Like this http://plnkr.co/edit/BBG5bkUpvo0MHkRAXtaU?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original issue was because `$timeout` was not injected in the controller. However you need to refrain from accessing DOM from your Controller. You could move the focus activity to a reusable directive and keep your controller simple.

Example:-

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.toggleEditor = function(){
  $scope.editorEnabled = !$scope.editorEnabled; //toggle editor view
}
}).directive('focus', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      set: "=" //Create a 2 way binding which you can bind it to editorEnabled
    },
    link:function(scope, elem){

      var unwatch = scope.$watch('set', function(v){
        if(v){
           elem.focus(); //focus on the element when value is set
        }
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
         unwatch(); //Just safe cleanup of the watch.
      });
    }
  }
});
```

and in your input set:-

```
<input type="text" id="email_editor" ng-model="user.local.email" ng-blur="toggleEditor()" 
              focus set="editorEnabled">
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ofNL6q?p=preview)**

Comment: @tommyd456 Sure i have set  a demo as well.

Comment: Gonna mark this right because it has put me on the right track (and it's very useful).